# ¿Qué es un bloque "static"?

Tags: java

Me he encontrado con un código Java que no sé interpretar.

La parte que he marcado no sé qué es, no me llega con los conocimientos que tengo.

¿Alguna referencia para poderlo consultar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
package hibernate1;
import org. hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionFactoryUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        static { 
            try { 
                sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                                .configure()
                                .buildSessionFactory();
            } catch ( Throwable ex ) { 
                System.err.println( 
                    "Err iniciando SessionFactory: " + ex
                );
                 throw new ExceptionlnlnitializerError( ex );
            } 
        } // static

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;
    } 
}
```

No entiendo la estructura. Declara la propiedad `sessionFactory`, y a continuación hay un bloque `static`, no sé que es eso.

Comment: No entiendo la estructura. Declara la propiedad sessionFactory, y a continuación hay un bloque static, no se que es eso.

Comment: Sinceramente, quien votó para cerrar desconoce de Java. Pido por favor que se abstengan de votar a cierre si no conocen la tecnología ni los términos que se usan en ella

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La estructura siguiente:

```
static {
  // ....
}
```

... se llama un **bloque de inicialización estático** (traduciendo mas o menos del inglés: **static initialization block**).

En cierta forma, actúa como un constructor de clase, pero en vez de inicializar los miembros de *instancia* de una clase, mas bien, el bloque de inicialización estático te permite inicializar los miembros *estáticos* de la clase, cosa que no puedes hacer con los constructores normales.

El bloque de inicialización estático se ejecuta una sola vez para una clase dada, sin importar cuantas instancias creas. Y tienes la garantía que se ejecutará antes de cualquier constructor de instancia.

En tu ejemplo, el bloque de inicialización estático sirve para inicializar la variable estática `sessionFactory`. El bloque se ejecuta una sola vez para la clase `SessionFactoryUtil` antes que tengas la oportunidad de usarla.

Puedes encontrar más información básica sobre esta estructura en el tutorial oficial de Oracle: [Static Initialization Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Si deseas información mas completa, pero mas técnica, puedes encontrarlo directamente en la especificación del lenguaje Java:

- [Static Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).
- [Initialization of Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4).

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.